# Find cell name with cell contents in Excel

Tags: excel

Say I have a table like this (the letters at the top and numbers down the side represent row/columns):

```
  | A |  B |  C |  D
------+----+----+----
1 | 1 | 2  |  3 |  4
2 | 5 | 6  |  7 |  8
```

and I want to find the cell name using the cell contents, so if the input into my function was 5, the function would return A2, as that is the position at which 5 is located.

Comment: This is so simple. What have you tried? If you haven't tried anything then you may want to see [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is within columns A to Z and there is only one occurrence of the particular value you are looking for, you can use the following formula:

```
=CHAR(SUMPRODUCT((A1:D2=5)*COLUMN(A1:D2))+64)&SUMPRODUCT((A1:D2=5)*ROW(A1:D2))
```

`SUMPRODUCT((A1:D2=5)*COLUMN(A1:D2))` returns the column number where 5 is located.

`SUMPRODUCT((A1:D2=5)*ROW(A1:D2))` returns the row number where 5 is located.

`CHAR(65)` gives `A`, so you add the column number to 64 to get the column letter.

E.g. if it is the first column, you get `CHAR(1+64)` which is `CHAR(65)` which is A.

[image]